# java.io.IOException: Unavailable shards for ranges

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

I'm getting the following error when I query my DSE cluster:

*java.io.IOException: Unavailable shards for ranges: [long list of numbers]*

The cluster is composed of 1 Cassandra node and 4 Solr nodes which were working fine previously. One thing that I noticed when I started getting the error is that Solr nodes 2 and 3 are down (DSE process is dead) while Solr node 1 is showing as "UL" (Up, Leaving) in "nodetool status".

Nodes 2 and 3 were brought back online by simply starting the DSE process again as standalone process, although there were several "FileNotFound" warnings during startup. I haven't taken any action yet for node 1.

My questions:

1. What could have caused the DSE process in nodes 2 and 3 to die?
2. What could have caused node 1 to "leave" the cluster (without me doing it) and how can I stop it?

**Edit:**
The nodes are divided into two DCs: The Cassandra node belongs to the "Cassandra" DC; the 4 Solr nodes belong to the "Solr" DC.

**Edit:**
Now, the nodes are showing conflicting "nodetool status" output when ran locally.

The Cassandra node is showing the following output:

```
Datacenter: Solr
================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                                  Rack
DL  <solr node 1>   306.5 GB   256     22.8%  69040f80-48fd-4425-817b-9550cb9490a6     rack1
DN  <solr node 2>   336.8 GB   256     25.1%  7dbbcc88-aabc-4cf4-a942-08e1aa325300     rack1
UN  <solr node 3>   316 GB     256     27.1%  c7db42c6-c5ae-439e-ab8d-c04b200fffc5     rack1
DN  <solr node 4>   444.88 GB  256     24.9%  30f411c3-7419-4786-97ad-395dfc379b40     rack1
Datacenter: Cassandra
=====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address              Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                                  Rack
UN  <cassandra node 1>   850.02 GB  256     0.1%   6ab7062e-47fe-45f7-98e8-3ee8e1f742a4     rack1
```

Solr node 1 is showing:

```
Datacenter: Solr
================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address                                   Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UL  <solr node 1>                             306.5 GB   256     22.8%  69040f80-48fd-4425-817b-9550cb9490a6  rack1
DN  <solr node 2>                             336.8 GB   256     25.1%  7dbbcc88-aabc-4cf4-a942-08e1aa325300  rack1
UN  <solr node 3>                             316.02 GB  256     27.1%  c7db42c6-c5ae-439e-ab8d-c04b200fffc5  rack1
DN  <solr node 4>                             444.88 GB  256     24.9%  30f411c3-7419-4786-97ad-395dfc379b40  rack1
Datacenter: Cassandra
=====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address             Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UN  <cassandra node 1>  850.42 GB  256     0.1%   6ab7062e-47fe-45f7-98e8-3ee8e1f742a4  rack1
```

And Solr node2 is showing:

```
Datacenter: Solr
================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address                                     Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UL  <solr node 1>                             303.26 GB  256     22.8%  69040f80-48fd-4425-817b-9550cb9490a6  rack1
UN  <solr node 2>                             336.8 GB   256     25.1%  7dbbcc88-aabc-4cf4-a942-08e1aa325300  rack1
UN  <solr node 3>                             310.52 GB  256     27.1%  c7db42c6-c5ae-439e-ab8d-c04b200fffc5  rack1
UN  <solr node 4>                             440.39 GB  256     24.9%  30f411c3-7419-4786-97ad-395dfc379b40  rack1
Datacenter: Cassandra
=====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address                     Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UN  <cassandra node 1>          834.34 GB  256     0.1%   6ab7062e-47fe-45f7-98e8-3ee8e1f742a4  rack1
```

Solr nodes 3 and 4 are also showing slightly different outputs but the fact is: All nodes are currently up and accessible (admin UI) - except that I receive the shard range error whenever I execute a query

Comment: There's clearly some kind of network problem preventing your nodes to correctly communicate, and even if each node is accessible by itself, none of them can reach enough nodes to generate a distributed query that can "cover" all token ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the solution for us is to restart all nodes. There were some nodes that failed to start on our first attempt to restart (lots of FileNotFoundException), but were able to proceed when we retried. This step solved the following problems:

- node 1 "leaving" the cluster (back to "normal" after restart)
- the nodes showing conflicting *nodetool status* output (all nodes show similar status after restart)

EDIT:
The problem with node 1 "leaving" the cluster happened again today. I noticed that the drive is full. Is this the reason for the automatic expulsion from the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you only have Solr search workloads in the DC in which you are using Solr. IOW, all nodes in a Solr/search DC must have Solr/search enabled. Non-Solr nodes in a Solr DC can confuse DSE/Solr when distributing queries.

Comment: Added the detail to my question